# Msg 512 error in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4OMd.png)

I wrote some SQL code.

The first code snippet executes without error, but when I try the second piece of code, I expect the same result, but it doesn't work.

Why does the second code snippet not work? Could anyone explain ?

Comment: The error tells you the problem.  There is more than one record returned from your subquery of Products where p.Category = c.CategoryID.

Comment: Looks like you actually need a `join` or an `apply`